# Hide Run Configurations from search everywhere results

Tags: intellij-idea

in the past there was an option to not show run configurations in the search everywhere results. With the latest update this seems to have been removed. Does anyone know, if the option still exists somewhere?

In the sourcecode there is still a check for "search.everywhere.configurations"
https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/lang-impl/src/com/intellij/ide/actions/SearchEverywhereAction.java

but even setting this in the registry does not work.

Thanks, 
Thorsten

Answer (score 1):

This option is still available in the old Search Everywhere dialog version which can be enabled by disabling the `new.search.everywhere` registry option.

The new Search Everywhere doesn't have this option yet, I've [opened an issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-204151).